# Z3 theory plug-in error

Tags: z3

I have created a custom theory plugin, which does nothing at the moment. The callbacks are all implemented and registered, but they simply return. Then, I read in a bunch of declare-consts, declare-funs, and asserts using Z3_parse_smtlib2_string, and pass the resulting ast to Z3_assert_cnstr. A subsequent call to Z3_check_and_get_model fails with the following error:

> The mk_fresh_ext_data callback was not set for user theory, you must use Z3_theory_set_mk_fresh_ext_data_callback

As far as I can tell, Z3_theory_set_mk_fresh_ext_data_callback does not exist.

Using the same string, but without registering the theory plugin, Z3_check_and_get_model returns sat and gives a model as expected.

I am using version 4 and the Linux 64 bit libraries.

The full example is here: http://pastebin.com/hLJ8hFf1

Comment: Simplified example [link](http://pastebin.com/rGB6jX2a)

Comment: Same with the assertions built using the API instead of parsing calls: [link](http://pastebin.com/ytzsbzpF). Also, the problem seems to be related to the use of forall. When the assertion has no forall, things work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the model-based quantifier instantiation module (MBQI). This module tries to create a copy of the main logical engine. To create the copy, Z3 must copy every theory plugin. It can do it for all builtin theories, but not for external theories.

The original theory plugin API did not have support for copying itself because it was implemented before the MBQI module. The API `Z3_theory_set_mk_fresh_ext_data_callback` is meant for that. However, it was not exposed yet for several reasons. 
The main issue is that Z3 4.0 has a new API for solvers. The current theory plugin API is incompatible with the new solver API. 
We are investigating ways of integrating them.
In Z3 4.0, the theory plugins only work with the old (deprecated) solver API.

To avoid the problem you described, you just have to disable the MBQI module. You can do that by setting `MBQI=false` when creating `Z3_context`.
In C, you can do that using the following code fragment.

```
Z3_config cfg; 
Z3_context ctx;
cfg = Z3_mk_config();
Z3_set_param_value(cfg, "MBQI", "false");
ctx = Z3_mk_context(cfg);
```

This also explains why your plugin works on quantifier-free formulas. The MBQI module is not used for this kind of formula.

Comment: Thanks! So at the moment, it looks like I can use theory plugins, or quantifiers, but not both. Is that accurate? (After setting MBQI to false, the above example no longer causes the error, but anything I've tried with a quantifier returns "unknown".) Also, is there a tutorial anywhere for the new solver/tactics API?

Comment: You can still used quantifiers but they will be processed using just the E-matching engine. Z3 can still show many formulas to be `unsat` using just E-matching. However, the E-matching engine will return `unknown` for any problem that is satisfiable. Is that the case for your examples?

Comment: Here is a link for online tutorials for tactics: http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial/strategies, http://rise4fun.com/z3py/tutorial/strategies

Comment: We have online tutorials describing the new solver API based on the Python API. http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/guide (Section Solvers).